# A proof in Linear Algebra with transverse matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$ U = \{A \in M_n\Bbb R : A^t = -A\}$
I need to show if the above subset of $M_n\Bbb R$ is actually a subspace
So to show a subset is a subspace it must agree with the following criteria:

- $U$ is not empty
- $u+v \in U$
- for all $a \in \mathbb R$, $au \in U$

So my thinking is that U is not empty because if we let $A^t$ = 0 vector then $-A$ is still equal to the zero vector.

I am unsure of proving whether not criteria 2 or 3 is valid or not. Looking for some help.

Comment: "**transposed**" matrices.

Answer (score 0):

if $$u,v \in U$$ then
$$u^t = -u$$ $$v^t= -v$$
we can get $$(u+v)^t=u^t+v^t=-u-v=-(u+v)$$
then $$u+v \in U$$

similar, if $$u \in U$$
we have $$(au)^t=a u^t=a (-u)=-(au)$$
then $$au \in U$$

So it is a subspace.

Comment: does the similar if part then cover multiplication?

Comment: that explanation makes sense tome